# Xaamrin.Forms Deserialize Object When Navigating In Shell App

Tags: json, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile

I am passing an object after serializing it to json, but when retrieving it and deserialize it I get an **TargetInovocationException**.

When Serializing:

```
Section section = sections.Find(x => string.Equals(x.Title, sections[pagesCreated -1].Title));
                    var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(section);
                    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(SectionDetailsPage)}?section={content}");
```

when deserializing:

```
  [QueryProperty(nameof(Section), "section")]
    public partial class SectionDetailsPage : ContentPage
    {
        private Section section;
        public string Section 
        { 
            set 
            {
                string content = Uri.UnescapeDataString(value);
                section = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Section>(content);
            }
        }
}
```

Section model:

```
public class Section
    {

        public Section() { }

        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string ImageURL { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: TargetInovocationException is usually a wrapper around other exceptions.  What is the actual exception causing the problem?

Comment: I think it is because the section object is being null.

Comment: that should be easy to test for and fix

Comment: @Jason it is being null because the deserializing is not happening, so it is null. I want to know ehy is the deserializing is not happening correctly.

Comment: I'd start by printing out the serialized data before and after the navigation, and verifying that it matches

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem was that I was calling a method that uses **section** and it was being called before calling the **set** method of the **Section** object which at that time "section" object will be null. So what I did is that I placed that function inside the **set** method.